# Huge dataset, ORDER BY date and limit

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I have a MySQL table with ~3.5mio lines. I want to iterate over each line. Since i do not want to load all 3.5mio lines, i split up the query seperating it into small ones. For the split i am using the date field.

The problem now is: When i select from the table with lines bigger than a specified date, it still looks after every date, puts them in a temporary list and than cuts of 90% of the entries since i only want small parts.

How can i create my query so that my computer does not crash it loads the whole table?

Comment: do you have any indexes on your table?

Comment: Not yet. Would it be recommended to use an index on my date column?

Comment: My suggestion would be to try that first to see if it makes any improvements on your query. My guess is it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to make sure your `ORDER BY` can be satisfied using an index, rather than requiring a filesort operation.

You can use EXPLAIN SELECT ...  to get the query plan.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (mytable_IX1)
 WHERE t.created_at > @last_created_at
    OR t.created_at = @last_created_at AND t.id > @last_id
 ORDER BY t.created_at, t.id
 LIMIT 1000


id select_type table  type  possible_keys key         key_len ref    rows Extra        
-- ----------- ------ ----- ------------- ----------- ------- ------ ---- -------------
 1 SIMPLE      t      range mytable_IX1   mytable_IX1 13      (NULL) 1000 Using where; Using index
```

On the first execution, you'd only need a `t.created_at IS NOT NULL` predicate.  On subsequent executions, you would pass in the values from the columns of the last row you fetched, so you would start your next query from that point.